# How to display all product prices for all user groups?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have 3 user groups defined: default/retail/wholesale. 
I have product with prices defined for each group.

Is it possible to display all prices for all user groups on product page?

I've checked `get_defined_vars()` at `flypage.tpl.php` but there is nothing about user groups and it's prices. Only price for currently auth user's user group...

Comment: maybe a standalone script that read the products/groups from the db ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yep, I've already made it via custom SQL query (right in `flypage.tpl.php`), but still seeking for right way of doing it :) It is my first meet with Joomla and Virtuemart

Comment: checkou the joomla api http://api.joomla.org/

Comment: VM api http://virtuemart.net/api/ ...